# chess in GWT+MVP and trying to store states in the local storage

Tags: java, gwt, local-storage, mvp, chess

I have done this till now

```
public void addStorage() {
    stockStore = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
    if (stockStore != null) {
        stockStore.setItem(("Index" + index), ("state" + HistoryCount));
        stockMap.put(("Index" + index), ("state" + HistoryCount));
    }
}

public void loadStorage() {
    String s;
    stockStore = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
    if (stockStore != null) {
        stockMap = new
        StorageMap(stockStore);
        for (int i = 0; i < stockStore.getLength(); i++) {
            if (stockMap.containsValue(index)) {
                s = stockStore.getItem("Index" + index);
                state = stateRecord.get(s);
                clearHighlights();
                setState(state);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what am I missing. These two functions are called by their handlers. Load and Save. load storage will load the stored state of chess and save will save the current chess state.

Comment: And what is the question ???

Comment: That this doesnt work. My states are still not being saved or loaded. Is there a problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have error here in `stockMap.containsValue(index)` but should be `stockMap.containsValue("Index" + index)`, the corrected version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stockStore.getLength(); i++) {
        if (stockMap.containsValue("Index" + index)) {
            s = stockStore.getItem("Index" + index);
            state = stateRecord.get(s);
            clearHighlights();
            setState(state);
            break;
        }
    }
```